# isometries in the plane

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question:

Suppose G is a finite group of Isometries in the plane. Suppose p is fixed by G. Prove that G is conjugate into O(2).

What exactly does "conjugate into O(2)" mean and how would I proceed?

Comment: Why did you delete the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173103/what-does-the-phrase-conjugate-into-mean-in-the-context-of-group-theory), which had already good explanations?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably what it means:

Let $t$ be the translation of $p$ to the origin $\mathcal O$. Then for each $g\in G$ (viewed as an isometry, just like $t$) you have that $tgt^{-1}$ is an isometry fixing $\mathcal O$.  So, the mapping $\phi(g)=tgt^{-1}$ is a group homomorphsm of $G$ into the orthogonal group $O(2)$ (the group of isometries of the plane fixing $\mathcal O$.)

$\phi$ is mapping the subgroup $G$ of the isometries to another subgroup of the isometries contained in $O(2)$, and in fact the map is obtained by conjugation.

Answer (score 0):

Given a group $\Gamma$ and two subgroups $G,H < \Gamma$, to say that "$G$ is conjugate into $H$" means that there exists $\gamma \in \Gamma$ such that $\gamma G \gamma^{-1} < H$.

In this case, $\Gamma$ is the full group of isometries of the plane $\mathbb R^2$ and $G$ is the given finite subgroup. If you know how to express $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb R^2$ coordinates using matrix and vector notation, then you should be able to understand how $O(2)$ is a subgroup. But what really helps is to know that from a geometric point of view, $O(2)$ is the subgroup of the isometries of $\mathbb R^2$ that fixes the origin $(0,0)$.

So to summarize, you are asked to find an isometry $\gamma$ for the case where $G$ is a finite subgroup fixing a certain point $p = (a,b) \in \mathbb R^2$, and $O(2)$ is the subgroup of all isometries fixing $(0,0)$.